# Command Line Backup tool over SSH with Versioning

Tags: mac, command-line, backup, bash, ssh

I am looking for command line backup tool for Mac OSX.  The features I am looking for:

- preferences for a backup are stored in a separate "profile" file so that one codebase can do more than one set of backups
- versioning
- backup destination can be locally attached drive, over ssh...
- email notifications
- automatic clean up of old backups
- MySQL backup
- will preserve Mac OSX metadata

  I have tried the following tools:
- eloy code.google.com/p/eloy/
- RubyGem Backup rubygems.org/gems/backup
- mlbackup maclemon.at/mlbackup

If you know of any others please post the address and any experience you have had with them.

Answer (score 1):

[rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) appears to meet most of your criteria.

- 'Profile' is just a cron job (at command) that schedules the backup with source and destination strings
- versioning, yup it's got that.
- runs local or over ssh, yup it's got that.
- email notification, part of the cron job, examples abound, google is your friend.
- clean up can just be another scheduled job.
- MySQL backup I dunno, never had a need for that.
- Mac OSX metadata, Docs say it does.  I don't run Mac OSX so you will have to verify on your own hardware.

Comment: Can it, in addition, compress the backup on the server side?